# Defining an iterated differential operator with compositions

Tags: function-construction, programming, symbolic

I'm a bit new to Mathematica so this question might be a bit basic.
Still, I could not find an answer.

I wish to define a symbolic differential operator.
Currently, I do something like the following:

```
op[g_] = g'
```

Now, I would like this operator to work well with compositions.
For example I would like

```
op[g^2].
```

to return $2g'*g'$. However I only get $(g^2)'$.

Another thing I'm hoping will work is to compose the operator with itself, so that

```
op[op[g]]
```

will return $g''$.

I understand that the problem is that the argument 'g' was never defined to be a 'function of x'. But I'm sure how to define everything correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function D:

```
op[g_] := D[g, x]
```

Then your result would be:

```
In[1]:= op[g[x]^2]
Out[2]= 2 g[x]g'[x]
```

And also

```
In[2]:= op[op[g[x]]]
Out[2]= g''[x]
```

Although I don't really see the point if the function D already exists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `g^2` does not represent the square of a function, that is, `(g^2)[x]` is not `g[x]^2`.  The system is not set up to operate that way. A similar thing could be said about `2 g * g'`, namely, that `*` does not perform the multiplication of functions.  To operate with functions, one can sometimes use `Composition` (`@*`) or pure functions.  Because of the way `Derivative` works, we are likely to end up with a pure-function expression anyway.

```
op[g_] := g'
```

To get `g^2`, compose `Power[#, 2]&` and `g`:

```
op[(#^2 &) @* g]
```

> ```
> (*  2 g[#1] Derivative[1][g][#1] &  *)
> ```